# How to circumvent PSR-2?

Tags: php, laravel, php-psr, php-fig

When Laravel 5.1 is upon us, PSR-2 will be enforced.

I'm a big fan of PHP-FIG, unfortunately for me I got really used to and comfortable with control structures in a new line.

Consider this current piece of code, already adhering to PSR-2:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    Cart::update($item, Input::get('qty_' .$item));
}
```

I understand the following is not PSR-2:

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
    Cart::update($item, Input::get('qty_' .$item));
}
```

But, how about these variations?

```
foreach($items as $item) Cart::update($item, Input::get('qty_' .$item));


foreach($items as $item)

    Cart::update($item, Input::get('qty_' .$item));


foreach($items as $item):

    Cart::update($item, Input::get('qty_' .$item));

endforeach;
```

As you can see, I got addicted to the white space resulting from the lead curly brace when going into a new line.

**Can any of the variations mentioned be considered properly PSR-2?**

Comment: "When Laravel 5.1 is upon us, PSR-2 will be enforced." Not on your code. Don't want to write PSR-2? Don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, none of those variations are PSR-2 compliant either. A control structure needs to have braces and there should be a space following the control structure name. These rules are defined rather explicitly here:

[Control Structure Guidelines](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#5-control-structures)

> - There MUST be one space after the control structure keyword
> - There MUST NOT be a space after the opening parenthesis
> - There MUST NOT be a space before the closing parenthesis
> - There MUST be one space between the closing parenthesis and the opening brace
> - The structure body MUST be indented once
> - The closing brace MUST be on the next line after the body